# Checking the string palindrome or not

Tags: java

i wrote following java code to find a string is palindrome or not.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Palindrome {   

        public static void main(String[] args){

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter the String");

            String str = sc.nextLine();

            sc.close();

            char[] word = str.toCharArray();

            boolean status = isPalindrome(word);

            if(status == true){
                System.out.println("Given String is Palindrome");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("String is not Palindrome");
            }

        }

        public static boolean isPalindrome(char[] word){
            int start = 0;
            int end = word.length - 1;
            while (end > start) {
                if (word[start] != word[end]) {
                    return false;
                }
                start++;
                end--;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

but its not working.I think something is missing. i dont know what went wrong. All kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is not working? any errors?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's working correctly. I'vs checked.

Comment: [I downvoted because "it's not working" isn't working as a problem description](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i am not a expert in java. But i think reversing the increment and decrement value of start and end will solve your issue.

++start;
 --end;

Comment: this doesn't matter.